# How secure is QEMU/KVM?

Tags: virtualization, kernel, kvm

I'm worrying about the security of the VM host machine (against guests) as the **K**ernel-Based **V**itrual **M**achine operates at kernel level.

**UPDATE:** Is there any guarantee that a guest can't manipulate/break the host system (execute instructions, etc.)?

**UPDATE** (to avoid "absolutism")**:** If there isn't any such guarantee, is the KVM less secure, than a non-K VM?

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it is easier to answer it exactly, as it is right now we could say "very" and it would be a valid answer. What is your concern? did you read something that make you doubt?

Comment: @Purefan see update

Comment: see http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=119318909016582

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee with any computational system that it can't be broken/manipulated.

Here is a [list of vulnerabilities in QEMU](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-7506/Qemu.html), its up to you to determine if your specific version is vulnerable or not, and how "easy" it is to be targeted.

As a side note: we tend to avoid absolutisms in infosec because there usually is no guarantee of anything, what is bullet proof today is a swiss cheese tomorrow.

Comment: Ideas are always bullet proof. ;)